# Google Fonts package Not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, google-fonts

The google_fonts package is not working in the final build apk in FLutter, it works fine in the debug mode, but as soon as I build it and install the final apk, It just shows regular font.

Comment: Having exactly the same issue as well. Any fixes?

Comment: It seems to be working with the latest release I believe, or maybe it was just a flutter build thing, try flutter clean and building it.

Comment: cool thanks! Will give it a try!

Comment: @sameerkashyap did you get this solved anyhow, I'm facing the same issue? TIA.

Comment: Did you initialize license for it?

Answer (score 11):

It could be because of internet permission issue, google fonts using internet acces and if don't apply the permission in your project it won't work when you install the app.

for this you need to add follow line to file AndroidManifest.xml which is there;
yourappname/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml

and the line you will add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: google_fonts package already contains the fonts and its installed in the local machine there is no need to use the internet to retrieve the fonts again.

Comment: To download fonts over http, android.permission.INTERNET permission should be added to <app_dir>/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml as well.

Comment: I don't know why but this actually worked for me, on `google_fonts: ^2.0.0` `flutter: 2.2.0`, in another project this permission isn't added, still working in that case. Anyway Thanks @Lunedor.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe it is an internet problem. Most times fonts using Flutter packages contain an error in the Pubspec file.

Check your Pubspec.yaml file. Make sure your google fonts package is Formatted this way

```
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_fonts: ^1.1.0

flutter:
  assets:
    - google_fonts/ # you only need this line and nothing in the fonts area per https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts
```

Comment: Thanks! Doesn't help that they show this right at the bottom of the readme

Comment: Brother thank you! That line worked for me. Please accept this answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

To use [google_fonts](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts) you must initialize the license for it.

##### To do that follow the steps:

*Suppose you using this:*

```
fontFamily: GoogleFonts.shadowsIntoLight().fontFamily,
```

Therefore, you are using ***shadowsIntoLight*** font.
To license it, first download the particular font from [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/).
After you download the zip files, extract it.

##### Make a folder named `google_fonts` in the root directory of your flutter app file.

=> Now place the `.ttf` and `OFL.txt` files `(present in the extracted folder)` in `google_fonts` folder that you made previously.

[Note: Only `OFL.txt` is enough for all your fonts.]

*This is how my one looks:*
[image]

##### Now go to `main.dart` file:

=> Add these lines inside the  `void main() {runApp(MyApp());}`:

```
void main() {
  LicenseRegistry.addLicense(() async* {
    final license = await rootBundle.loadString('google_fonts/OFL.txt');
    yield LicenseEntryWithLineBreaks(['google_fonts'], license);
  });

  runApp(...);
}
```

and import the followings:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

##### Now close your app and restart it and the release it:

```
flutter build apk --release
```

Comment: This answer got me most of the way there. As of `google_fonts 6.2.1`, it is also  necessary to include an `assets:` line for the `google_fonts` folder in the `pub spec.yaml` file.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added the below line in /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

hello my friend try to check the version first ;)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuyIa.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`Google fonts` uses internet, so you may have to update the dependencies in the `manifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Else you can try to make the `google font` available in the `offline` by adding it in the assets folder.

And then change the code from

```
// Online Code
Text(
  'This is hammersmithOne from Google Font'
  style: GoogleFonts.hammersmithOne(),
),
```

to

```
// Offline Code
Text(
  'This is hammersmithOne from Google Font',
   style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'hammersmithOne') // This is loaded from assets
),
```

For futher reference refer [this](https://www.flutterbeads.com/google-fonts-in-flutter/) article.